# Trying to sculpt using tablet but can only sculpt using when holding control. (mouse sculpting works fine)

Tags: sculpting

Any help? everything else seems to work fine, it even registers my stylus presses as "left click" on other parts of the UI but not for sculpting unless i hold control.